# onPress handler not being fired over TouchableHighlight on Android

Tags: android, react-native, touchableopacity, touchablehighlight, touchablewithoutfeedback

We are experiencing a weird issue. The thing is that when you press the button, for some reason the Highlight to the underlayColor is occurring but the Touchable is not firing the onPress handler.

The onPress handler is ran if you continue pressing the button (like in a long press event)

Any ideas? We are still using an old version of RN which is 0.59.9. I would like to add that on iOS the behavior is the expected.

**Update (code):**

```
<TouchableHighlight
    activeOpacity={0.5}
    disabled={disabled}
    delayPressIn={0}
    delayLongPress={0}
    onPress={onPress}
    underlayColor={hexWithOpacity(Palette.Primary, 0.05)}
    style={[
      styles.container,
      buttonStyles(disabled)[variant],
      buttonContainerDimmensions()[size],
      style,
    ]}
    {...props}
  >
    <Text
      style={[
        buttonTextStyles(disabled)[variant],
        buttonFontDimmensions()[size],
      ]}
    >
      {title}
    </Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: hey can you please share same code? maybe ill check that and youll get help

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: @halbano did you find a solution to this? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

onPress={onPress} should be a function like

```
onPress={() => {console.log('onPress')}}
```

or

```
onPress={this.onPress}
```

where onPress is defined as a function somewhere